# Получить информацию о лентах, на которые продано больше 2 билетов

Tags: sql, запрос, ms-access

есть две таблицы:

1)

```
Код ленты |Название   | Язык
1          Фильм1     | Английский
2          Фильм2     | Английский
3          Фильм3     | Английский
```

2)

```
Код билета  | Код ленты
421         | 1
132         | 1
534         | 2
74          | 1
544         | 3
323         | 1
```

Надо выбрать только те фильмы, на которые продано больше двух билетов в данном случае это "Фильм1" — 4 билета. Как составить такой запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, вы не написали имена таблиц и колонок.
Если взять следующие имена:
Таблица 1 - table1(id, name, language)
Таблица 2 - table2(ticket_code, code_id)
Можно составить запрос вроде:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.code_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.name
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Comment: "Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM"

Comment: Вы укажите названия своих таблиц и колонок. Либо внимательно посмотрите, правильно ли вы перенесли названия своих таблиц на мой запрос.

Comment: Таблица 1 - Лента(Код, Название, Язык) Таблица 2 - Сеансы(Код билета, Лента)

Comment: Покажите ваш запрос

Comment: SELECT т1.Название FROM Сеансы т2 JOIN Лента т1 ON т2.Лента = т1.Код GROUP BY т1.Название HAVING count(*) > 2

Comment: Вроде верный запрос. Теперь напишите ошибку

Comment: Выдаёт: "Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM"

Comment: А вы напрямую из базы выполняете этот запрос? Или из кода приложения?

Comment: Только что попробовал ввести SQL запрос напрямую в Access, итог тот же, точно такая же ошибка

Comment: У меня нет большого опыта работы с Access, но запрос валидный, только что проверил на PostgreSQL с той же структурой таблиц. Судя по всему есть особенности синтаксиса в Access. Попробуйте задавать алиасы через AS, то есть FROM Сеансы AS т2 JOIN Лента AS т1

Comment: Проблема была в "JOIN", исправил на "LEFT JOIN" и всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: Да, действительно, Access требует INNER JOIN вместо JOIN

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT лента.Код_лента, лента.Название, лента.Язык, count(*) AS cnt
FROM лента
LEFT JOIN билет ON билет.Код_лента = лента.Код_лента
WHERE билет.Код_билета IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY лента.Код_лента, лента.Название, лента.Язык
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Comment: "Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'count(*' "

Comment: Поправил `count` конечно же.